# Selecting max value from 2nd table in first table results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables as below-

Table I

```
ID  DATE
1   05/11/12
2   23/11/12
3   29/11/12
4   04/10/12
5   20/11/12
```

And another table (IH) with the following info-

```
ID  RECNO   NOTE
1   1       Open
1   2       Update
1   3       Close
2   1       Open
2   2       Update
2   3       Hold
2   4       Close
3   1       Open
4   1       Open
4   2       Update
5   1       Open
```

I would like to output a result as shown below, displaying the Note field using the highest value of RecNo for each ID. So using the data above the output should be-

```
ID  DATE        NOTE
2   23/11/12    Close
3   29/11/12    Open
```

The code I have is-

```
SELECT I.ID, I.DATE, IH.NOTE FROM
I I, IH IH
JOIN (SELECT MAX([RECNO]) [RECNO] FROM
IH
GROUP BY RECNO) IH2 ON IH2.ID = IH.ID AND
IH2.[RECNO] = IH.[RECNO]
JOIN I I2 ON I2.ID = IH.ID WHERE
(I2.DATE>={TS ‘2012-11-22 00:00:002}) GROUP BY I2.ID
```

However when I execute the code I get-

```
Invalid Column Name 'RECNO'. Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Note, haven't tried it, I'm on my Mac at the moment.

```
SELECT I.ID, I.DATE, IH.NOTE
FROM I I
OUTER APPLY 
  (SELECT TOP 1 *
   FROM IH 
   WHERE IH.ID = I.ID
   ORDER BY RECNO DESC) IH    
WHERE I.DATE >= '2012-11-22'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is rather, uh, messy.

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 or greater, you can use the `row_number()` function, as follows:

```
SELECT I.ID, I.DATE, IH.NOTE
FROM I join
     (select ih.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by id order by recno desc) as seqnum
      from IH
     ) ih
     on IH2.[RECNO] = IH.[RECNO] and seqnum = 1
WHERE I2.DATE>='2012-11-22 00:00:002'
```

This is assigning a sequence number in the IH table, for each id with the highest record number getting the value "1".  The rest is just SQL.

Your original query is simply not correct syntactically, but I think this is what you want based on the description.

Answer (score 0):

and another one

```
SELECT I.ID, I.DATE
,(Select TOP 1 IH.NOTE FROM IH where IH.ID=i.ID Order by Recno DESC) as Note
from I
WHERE
I.DATE>'20121122'
```

Comment: hmm I get incorrect column expression:'[SELECT TOP 1 IH.NOTE FROM IH WHERE IH.ID=I.ID ORDER BY RECNO DESC)'.

Comment: tis works fine for me ..... did you use [ SELECT instead of ( SELECT -----
create table #ih (ID int,  RECNO int,   NOTE varchar(10))
insert into #ih values 
(1,   1,       'Open'),
(1,   2,       'Update'),
(1,   3,       'Close'),
(2,   1,       'Open'),
(2,   2,       'Update'),
(2,   3,       'Hold'),
(2,   4,       'Close');
Create Table #i(ID int,  [DATE] datetime)
insert into #i values (1,'20120101'),(2,'20120101');

SELECT I.ID, I.DATE
,(Select TOP 1 IH.NOTE FROM #IH ih where IH.ID=i.ID Order by Recno DESC) as Note
from #i I

Drop table #i
Drop table #ih

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```
SELECT a.ID, a.DATE, b.NOTE FROM a
inner join  b on a.ID = b.ID
where b.recno in (select max(bb.recno)
               from b as bb where bb.id = b.id)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd141/2

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the different identifiers, look at this solution:

```
select t1.MyID, t1.MyDate, y.Note
from t1
join
(
    select MyID, max(RecNo) as RecNo
    from t2
group by MyID
) x
    on t1.MyID = x.MyID
left join
(
    select *
    from t2
) y
    on t1.MyID = y.MyID
and x.RecNo = y.RecNo
where t1.MyDate >= '2012.11.22'
```

The complete solution is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ca09/3

**Update:** Oops, forgot to bring in the date in where clause. Updated SQL Fiddle and the query above.